# HLS.js get video segment info

Tags: javascript, hls.js

I am trying to get analytics on hls.js from my video segments.
I am looking for the size of the video segments and what time the video segments go over the network.

I am currently using the HLS events with not much luck:

```
this.hls.on(HLS.Events.BUFFER_APPENDING, (event, data) => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log('segment added to buffer');
});
```

I've tried BUFFER_APPENDED, BUFFER_APPENDING, FRAG_CHANGED, without much luck getting the info I want.

Comment: @johmbumble did you try `LEVEL_LOADED` or `FRAG_BUFFERED`? Demo folder in repository has good level of stats collection you might be able to use it: https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/tree/master/demo

Comment: yes I was using the wrong event:
something like:

  this.hls.on(HLS.Events.FRAG_BUFFERED, (event, stats) => {
   //console.log('total =  ' + stats.stats.tfirst);
   console.log('total =  ' + (stats.stats as any).total);
  });

was what I needed

Comment: @johmbumble awesome, do you mind if I add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FRAG_BUFFERED` or `LEVEL_LOADED` event should have stat information you need.

Demo folder in repository has good level of stats collection you might be able to use it for collecting stats:
https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/tree/master/demo